# SignalR windows firewall settings

Tags: websocket, signalr, firewall

I built a signalR service that my WPF application uses and in development everything worked fine (since its running locally).
When it came to test environment, when I published it (on remote windows server 2008 r2 as windows service) I had error connecting.
The service runs on port 8080 and when I tried to run it on port 80 (I had to remove IIS for that) it worked fine so I assume its firewall problems.
I need an explanation of how to make it work (I had in mind that maybe because its duplex connection things work different) and since its for intranet app i'll have to ask my IT manager for opening these ports,